# @ character in email encoding

Tags: java, http, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm sending email and password as form parameters "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with a HttpPost (Apache Http Client) instance. My problem is that the email value is encoded to "someEmail%40gmail.com" which should be "someEmail@gmail.com".

```
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  for (Entry<String, String> entry: params.entrySet())
       nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

  UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair);
  post.setEntity(formEntity);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's fine. The `@` character is not valid in a URL (`x-www-form-urlencoded`), it must be properly encoded.

Your server should have no problem decoding it.